# Check if the decimal value of a variable is infinite or not

Tags: python

I would like to check if the decimal value of a variable is infinite or not, and I found a solution from [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-decimal-is_finite-method/). But I am having a problem:

```
from decimal import *
a = input("Enter a number: ") #I enter 1/3 which it's decimal part should be infinite.
a = str(a)
if type(a) == str:
    a = str(eval(a)) 
    print(type(a))
else:
    if a.endswith(".0"):
        l = len(a)
        a = a[:l-2]

if "." in a:
    a = Decimal(a)
    if a.is_finite:
        print("the decimal part of", a, "is finite")
    else:
        print("the decimal part of", a, "is infinite")
```

But the problem is that it's saying that `a` is finite.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem or another way to check if the decimal value of a variable is infinite or not?

Comment: A fraction is "finite" in base 10 if its denominator's prime factors are only 2 and 5.  (This assumes that the fraction is in reduced form.  I.e. 9/6 needs to be reduced to 3/2, which is "finite").

Comment: The problem of your code is the `if-statement` it should be `if a.is_finite()` where you forgot to call the function. It was returning a string earlier and thus got treated as true, that's why it outputs finite ALWAYS.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with finite numbers. The code seems to suggest that the objective is to find numbers with *recurring* values after the decimal point - e.g., as would be generated by 1/3. The question is whether (for example) 2/11 (i.e., 0.18 recurring) needs to be considered as True or False in this context

Answer (score 2):

"Infinite" doesn't mean what you think it means. I think you're looking for numbers with nonterminating decimal representations. You won't be able to use `decimal` for that, because it doesn't support numbers with nonterminating representations at all.

```
a = str(a)
```

Unless you're using Python 2, `input` always returns a `str`. There's no need to convert the result to one.

```
if type(a) == str:
```

You just converted `a` to `str` (and it was already one anyway), so this is always true and the `else` branch will never run.

```
a = str(eval(a))
```

If `a` was `'1/3'` before, this will convert it to `'0.3333333333333333'`, which is a terminating decimal: it has exactly 16 `3`s in it.

```
if a.is_finite:
```

`a.is_finite` is the `is_finite` method of `a`. Methods always test true. To find out if `a` is finite, you need to call the method:

```
if a.is_finite():
```

But even with that fix, it will still say that 1/3 is finite, because it is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a [mathematic](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/algebra_book/online_problems/finite_or_inf_rep.htm#s25) way of solving the problem?

1. Get the fraction into its simplest form.
2. Factor the denominator into primes.
3. If the denominator contains any prime other than 2 and 5, then the rational number has infinite decimals.

So the pseudo-code:

```
num = input()

denominator = num[num.find('/') + 1:]

denominator_primes = factor_denominator(denominator) 
# this asumes that factor_denominator function returns a set (unique values)
if len(denominator_primes) > 2:
    num has infinite decimals
else:
    if 2 not in denominator_primes or 5 not in denominator_primes:
        num has infinite decimals
    else:
        num has finite decimals
```

But you can basically stop factoring if you encounter any prime other than 2 and 5, this will save some computation. Factoring a number into its prime factors is a computationally heavy task.